# EF Core Migration error: "Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationContext'"

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to do the migration with EF Core but I get an error - how can I fix this error?

```
PM> add-migration ini
```

> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationContext'. Add an
> implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to
> the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for
> additional patterns supported at design time.

Comment: What version you currently use for EF core ?

Comment: Make sure that you have selected the default project (which has DBContext) in Package Manager console. And you have selected your host project (which has startup.cs) as the startup project before running the above command

Answer (score 11):

This will also happen if you have multiple start-up projects - when migrating, just select one (in VS right click Solution and Set StartUp Projects...)

Comment: Selecting the main application did it for me. Thank you.

Comment: It's not a good idea to change startup project in solution for migration, it's better to set startup project in package manager console by -StartupProject .

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue with asp.net core 3.1.
For me, it was pretty straight forward, adding an implementation of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` to the main web project fixed the issue.

A basic implementation looks something like this:

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<YourDbContext>
{
    public YourDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourDbContext >();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return new YourDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Please refer to [this](https://codingblast.com/entityframework-core-idesigntimedbcontextfactory/) blog post on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

It is highly probably because of your  default startup project:

Open Package manager console and write this command:

```
 PM> Add-Migration -StartupProject[YourProjectPath(just press a tab all the.csproj paths will come up, and then choose your DataBaseLayer project to execute a migration for)] migrationName
```

In this way you don't need to again go to solution and set startup
project with your webProject whenever you finished adding a new migration.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error because I have two separated projects: Data Models and ApplicationContext are defined in MyProject.Data while Program.cs is in MyProject.UI. So I have to specify them as follows:

```
dotnet ef migrations add v1.0 --project MyProject.Data --startup-project MyProject.UI
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when creating a migration. In my code in the ApplicationContext constructor, I used the *Database.EnsureCreated()* method. Typically this method is used for small applications where you need to check for the existence of a database and create it once. When creating an application with a database that will change with new versions and using migrations, you should not use this method.

Answer (score 1):

It's unobvious, but this error message also appears if there are any exceptions in a `DbContext` constructor or in `OnConfiguring` method.

For example, `Database.EnsureCreated()` can fail because of incorrect connection string or disabled database.

**Tip**: to find out the problem root, just wrap your code in try catch and display your exception using `Console.WriteLine();`

Answer (score 0):

1.Modify your code in ConfigureService with :

```
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),

        x => x.MigrationsAssembly("WebApplication")));
```

2. In command line which includes WebApplication.csproj:

`dotnet ef migrations add Init`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error existed because I was [applying migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime). After removing `Database.Migrate();` in my code, I was able to add the new migration without errors.

By the way, I used [EF Core .NET command-line interface (CLI) tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet), not the Package Manager Console (I run into problems I couldn't solve when I was using the Package Manager Console, so I went for the CLI alternative, and it was worth the change).

Also, make sure you use [the appropriate options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options) to select [your startup project and your target project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#target-project-and-startup-project).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when the Primary Key for the table was not set manually (with attributes or with FluentAPI) and was not determined automatically (not "Id" kayword and not "TableName" + "Id")

Stack: ASP.NET Core EF + Postgres (Npgsql)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding a constructor to ApplicationContext